# How to create a SoapUI project with client certificate authentication

Tags: mule, soapui, x509certificate, client-certificates

I have X509 certificate implementation in one of my projects and i want to use Client certificate while consuming it from SoapUI. I got some solution [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx)
but it applies the same certificate for all the invocations from SoapUI. what if I have different certificates for different services that I invoke? How can I add the client certificate in my SOAP request itself?

Comment: Double Click on project --> WS-Security Configuration -->KeyStore   place you can add more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many trutstore or keystore based on the requirement.Double click on the name of the project-> Go to WS-Security Config. Please find few useful urls

http://pglezen.github.io/was-config/html/soapui.html ( Check config SOAP UI)

https://www.soapui.org/blog/ws-security-settings.html.

Based on the SOAPUI version. Truststore and Keystore tab will vary. But all with the same configuration.

Comment: Thanx @Star for the solution. it really helps.
sorry for making a delay in marking the answer.

Answer (score 2):

SSL Settings at the request level can be done the following way:

1. Double click on the Project name
2. In the "WS-Security Configurations" tab, click on "Keystores" tab click, then on the green "+" to add a keystore:

[image]

3. Enter the keystore location and password
4. Click on the Request
5. Change the request property "SSL keystore" to the one added in step 2-3:

[image]

6. You can now run the request

Source: https://blogs.sap.com/2011/01/06/soap-ui-tool-soap-https-client-authentication/