# SoapUI SOAP Project request using client certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, soapui, x509certificate, pfx

Using Zeep in Python, I was able to successfully make a SOAP request to a particular Web Service I am trying to connect to. However, I am unable to do this in SoapUI. The issue is the Web Service requires a client side certificate, and I am unable to load this in SoapUI the same way I do with Zeep in Python. I have followed the instructions at [How to create a SoapUI project with client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434154/how-to-create-a-soapui-project-with-client-certificate-authentication) but it still isn't working.

I have the client certificate as both a `.pfx` file and separated as a `.cer` and `.key` file that contains the public key certificate and the private key respectively. This worked with Zeep when I gave it the two separate `.cer` and `.key` files, and I want to do the same thing in SoapUI. However, when I go to add them in the Keystore section, I can only add the `.pfx` file and not the two separate files. In short, what do I do to add a client side certificate?

I also want to note I'm not really sure what a Keystore is as web searching indicates it has to do with Java Keystore but that isn't what I'm doing at all. I'm using a standard X.509 certificate, and when I load the `.crt` or `.key` file into the Keystore it gives a Java error. I'm new to SoapUI and overall just a little confused by it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to finally connect. After adding the certificate to the KeyStore, I added the certificate to the `SSL Keystore` property as indicated in the screenshot where I have the cert blacked out and it worked.

To add a certificate to the KeyStore, double click on the project name, click WS-Security Configurations, then Keystores and it can be done there.

[image]